# Needs help on merging the csv files in loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have shell script which is calling sql file and executes based on db count and creates output csv files, which is working fine, below example.

```
  ....
    for (( i=1;i<=$count;i++ ))
    sqlplus connection << EOF
    spool csv_$i
    @slqfile.sql 
    exit
    EOF
    ....
```

And I wanted to remove the first two lines from second file onwards, below code will give the only last loop count csv file data in combined.csv

```
 ....
 for (( i=1;i<=$count;i++ ))
                  do
    cat csv_$i.csv > combined.csv
              if [ $i -gt 1 ]; then
                              cat csv_$i.csv | sed -i '1,2d' > combined.csv
                  fi
    done
    ....
```

Please help me on merging the all files into one file in the loop by removing the first two lines ffrom second file onwards.

Comment: `> combined.csv` -> `>> combined.csv`. `>` truncates the file. `>>` appends to file.

Comment: @KamilCuk, yes but if use append it will get appended with for each time when I execute script, I don't want that, I need only current execution output  to be in combined file.

Comment: So what do you think the solution would be? So truncate the file once or remove the file before entering the loop... I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: @KamilCuk, thanks for the help, for now I do't have any thought except removing before for loop, is there any way other than this.